# Django: how to send form data from one page to the next?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

**The basic problem is that I can not find out a way of taking the form data to pass on to the next page?**

Extra information:
I read somewhere that I should use session, which seems sensible, however, serialization appears not to work with forms without a model, however, I could be wrong.

When I click submit the error is `AttributeError: 'BoundField' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

**Form**

```
class ItemCounterForm(Form):
    item = CharField(max_length=30)
    counter = IntegerFeild(min_value=1, max_value=1000)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemCounterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**View**

```
class ItemCounterView(View):
    FormSet = formset_factory(ItemCounterForm)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': self.FormSet()
        }
        return render(request, 'app:template', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.FormSet(self.request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            for single_form in form:
                data_form = serializers.serialize('json', single_form)
                request.session['form'] = data_form
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('app:next_page'))
        else:
            context = {
                'form': self.FormSet()
            }
            return render(request, 'app:template', context)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please fix white space and indentation.

Comment: @cezar Thanks. I hope it's better now.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by sending it to the next page. Please show how the view for `app:next_page` would look for us to better understand what you intend to achieve.

Comment: How about using `FormView`? It has an attribute `success_url`, where you could specify your next page and in the method `form_valid` you could implement the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intending on saving your data to the database. The simplest solution would be to pass it as parameters in the url something like the following:

```
url(r'^'your_url_name'/(?:(?P<item>[a-z]+)/)?(?:(?P<counter>[0-9]+)/)?$', views.'your_view_name'),
```

That is in case any of the parameters could be blank or null. If that is not your case remove the extra question mark symbols. For defining your view you would pass on addition of the request parameter the item and counter parameter.

The validation you could do perform it on the client side. Cheers.